# Visual Studio Code Analysis Deadlock

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis, fxcop, fxcopcmd

I am getting a deadlock error when I run code analysis from VS2013. I'm pretty sure all I need to do is increase or disable the deadlock timeout because I can run code analysis with standalone FX Cop 10. Is there something I can do to the csproj file to disable deadlock protection?

Answer (score 1):

Would this help ?

[VS2013 FxCop CA0001 : FxCop appears to have hung or deadlock](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e1a8841-3cad-43a7-8279-816102715cc8/vs2013-fxcop-ca0001-fxcop-appears-to-have-hung-or-deadlock?forum=vsdebug)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me. I doubt that code analysis has such granular settings exposed via msbuild, so all you can do in my opinion is to log a bug with Microsoft:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Or simply hit the sad face in the top right corner of VS and send a frown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CodeAnalysisTimeout` property of MSBuild. `msbuild /p:CodeAnalysisTimeout=240` will result in `/timeout=240` passed to `FxCopCmd.exe`.